# How do I make this model of a digital camera?

Tags: modeling

I want to make a Black Magic pocket cinema camera model in Blender

[image]

but I am unable to make the portion shown in picture. My picture looks like this

[image]

It looks nowhere near what I intend to do, can anyone tell me how to make this model?

[image]

Comment: Do you have the physical camera? More photos of it?

Comment: I do not have physical camera, but I can get more pictures from Internet.

Comment: That's where you should start. An experienced modeller would struggle same as you without popper reference. Get as many photographs from all sides as possible so you understand the shape.

Comment: Always try to search for high resolution images you might get lucky like with this one: https://sydneydesign.com.au/2014/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Blackmagic-Pocket-Cinema-Camera-1.jpg It should be a lot easier when you have this for reference.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would start with a cube. Make the cube the approximate dimensions of the camera, then start subdividing, adding loops, moving faces, until you have the shape, then go and add the smaller details.

Starting from an extruded shape as you have there will not make it easy to get a nice smooth end result, and you will find adding the details is more difficult.